# On a specific C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

How to describe the C*-algebra $C^*(\eta, \eta^*)/<\eta^*\eta=\mu \eta \eta^*>$ where $\mu$ is a positive real number less than $1$? What happens if $\mu$ is replaced by a complex number? Any hint/suggestion/reference will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a C*-algebra $A$ is generated by an element $\eta $ satisfying $\eta^*\eta=\mu \eta \eta^*$,  where $\mu$ is a positive
real number less than $1$,  then $\eta =0$, and hence
$A=\{0\}$.  The reason is that
$$
  \|\eta \|^2 = \|\eta ^*\eta \| = \mu \|\eta \eta^*\| = \mu \|\eta\|^2,
  $$
which imply that $\|\eta \|=0$.

If $\mu $ is any complex number not equal to $1$, one also deduces that $\eta =0$, because of comparison  of spectra:
$$
  \sigma (\eta \eta ^*) \cup \{0\} =
  \sigma (\eta ^*\eta ) \cup \{0\} =
  \sigma (\mu \eta \eta ^*) \cup \{0\} =
  \mu \sigma (\eta \eta ^*) \cup \{0\},
  $$
while the only nonempty subset $S\subseteq {\mathbb R}_+$ such that $\mu S=S$ is the set $S=\{0\}$.

Comment: This answer looks correct if $\eta$ is bounded. I missed this important fact in the question. What if $\eta$ is unbounded and it generates the C*-algebra in the sense of affiliation relation?

Comment: I am not aware of a well established theory of C*-algebra presentations envolving unbounded operators.